# PERL databases to file

Tags: perl

Currently I am working on my exam project and I require some assistance.

The goal from this script is to select data from a MySQL database and put this in a file with a specific line length and even a specific column length. The required length for each field and more make-up is located in a different database. So far so good, so what I've done is I made two arrays: one for the make up (columns, DB1) and another one for the data (DB2). Now the problem is each line has to make 256 characters, there are those fillers which are located in the make up database but not in the data one, so at the point where the filler field comes up, everything messes up. I tried loads of things, but I can't figure out what to do, and since its my exam project, my whole study kinda relies on it.

```
$expsel->bind_columns(\$tabelnaam,\$huidige,\$id);
while($expsel->fetch()) {

    $tbl        = substr($tabelnaam, 0,4);
    $tblnr      = substr($tabelnaam, 2,2);

    $i = 0;
    $exp_spec = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblExportspecificatie WHERE tabelnaam = '".$tbl."' ORDER BY id");
    $exp_spec->execute();
    $exp_spec->bind_columns(\$id, \$tblnaam, \$vldnaam, \$vldlngte, \$ascii, \$telveld, \$tellen, \$keystring);
    while($exp_spec->fetch()){
        if($i == 0){
            @AoA = ([ $tbl, $vldnaam, $vldlngte, $ascii, $telveld, $tellen, $keystring ]);
        }else{
            push @{ $AoA[$i] }, $tbl, $vldnaam, $vldlngte, $ascii, $telveld, $tellen, $keystring;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $exp_spec->finish();

    # Start regel wegschrijven aan het begin van de nieuwe tabel reeks
    # printf FILE "10".$tblnr.pad2str(252, 1, "").chr(10);

    $tbl_data = $dba->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$tbl." LIMIT 5");
    $tbl_data->execute();

    $regels = $tbl_data->rows;

    my @array;
    while ( my @arr = $tbl_data->fetchrow_array() ) {
        push @array,\@arr;
    }

    for($s = 0; $s < $regels; $s++){
        for($x = 0; $x < $i; $x++){
            if($x == 0){
                if($AoA[0][1] eq "F0101" || $AoA[0][1] eq "F6115"){
                    printf FILE $tblnr.pad2str(4, 0, $gemeentecode).pad2str(8, $AoA[0][3], $array[$s][$x]);
                }else{
                    printf FILE $tblnr.pad2str($AoA[0][2], $AoA[0][3], $array[$s][$x]);
                }
            }else{
                printf FILE pad2str($AoA[$x][2], $AoA[$x][3], $array[$s][$x]);
            }

        }
        printf FILE "--".chr(10);
    }
    printf FILE chr(10);
    print Dumper @AoA;
    print Dumper @array;

    @$AoA = 0;      
}
```

And here are the dumps for the arrays

```
$VAR1 = [
          'st31',
          'F0120',
          '9',
          '0',
          '0',
          '0',
          ''
        ];
$VAR2 = [
          'st31',
          'F1110',
          '24',
          '1',
          '0',
          '0',
          ''
        ];
$VAR3 = [
          'st31',
          'F1120',
          '5',
          '0',
          '0',
          '0',
          ''
        ];
$VAR4 = [
          'st31',
          'F1130',
          '1',
          '1',
          '0',
          '0',
          ''
        ];
$VAR5 = [
          'st31',
          'F1140',
          '4',
          '1',
          '0',
          '0',
          ''
        ];
$VAR6 = [
          'st31',
          'F1150',
          '2',
          '1',
          '0',
          '0',
          ''
        ];
$VAR7 = [
          'st31',
          'F1160',
          '6',
          '1',
          '0',
          '0',
          ''
        ];
$VAR8 = [
          'st31',
          'F1020',
          '40',
          '1',
          '0',
          '0',
          ''
        ];
$VAR9 = [
          'st31',
          'F1310',
          '40',
          '1',
          '0',
          '0',
          ''
        ];
$VAR10 = [
           'st31',
           'F8110',
           '1',
           '1',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR11 = [
           'st31',
           'F8120',
           '8',
           '2',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR12 = [
           'st31',
           'F8130',
           '8',
           '2',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR13 = [
           'st31',
           'F1170',
           '40',
           '1',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR14 = [
           'st31',
           'F0121',
           '10',
           '0',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR15 = [
           'st31',
           'F0130',
           '8',
           '0',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR16 = [
           'st31',
           'FILLER',
           '4',
           '1',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR17 = [
           'st31',
           'F0140',
           '10',
           '0',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR18 = [
           'st31',
           'F0220',
           '2',
           '1',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR19 = [
           'st31',
           'FILLER',
           '1',
           '1',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR20 = [
           'st31',
           'F0410',
           '1',
           '1',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR21 = [
           'st31',
           'F0310',
           '8',
           '2',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR22 = [
           'st31',
           'F0810',
           '8',
           '2',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR23 = [
           'st31',
           'F0811',
           '1',
           '1',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR24 = [
           'st31',
           'FILLER',
           '5',
           '1',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR25 = [
           'st31',
           'F1010',
           '1',
           '1',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR26 = [
           'st31',
           'FILLER',
           '7',
           '1',
           '0',
           '0',
           ''
         ];
$VAR1 = [
          '170805955',
          'Waterlelie              ',
          '16',
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          '3434VK',
          'Nieuwegein                              ',
          undef,
          'I',
          '2010-01-01',
          '2011-01-01',
          undef,
          '356000000',
          '0',
          '2147483647',
          undef,
          'V',
          '1946-10-24',
          '0000-00-00',
          'A',
          'W'
        ];
```

So I think the problem is because the column array has more data then the data one, so at the point of the filler, the counter messes up... here's some more debug data:

```
<<DEBUG>> L-> 9 AS-> 0, DATA-> 170805955 
<<DEBUG>> L-> 24 AS-> 1, DATA-> Waterlelie               
<<DEBUG>> L-> 5 AS-> 0, DATA-> 16 
<<DEBUG>> L-> 1 AS-> 1, DATA->  
<<DEBUG>> L-> 4 AS-> 1, DATA->  
<<DEBUG>> L-> 2 AS-> 1, DATA->  
<<DEBUG>> L-> 6 AS-> 1, DATA-> 3434VK 
<<DEBUG>> L-> 40 AS-> 1, DATA-> Nieuwegein                               
<<DEBUG>> L-> 40 AS-> 1, DATA->  
<<DEBUG>> L-> 1 AS-> 1, DATA-> I 
<<DEBUG>> L-> 8 AS-> 2, DATA-> 2010-01-01 
<<DEBUG>> L-> 8 AS-> 2, DATA-> 2011-01-01 
<<DEBUG>> L-> 40 AS-> 1, DATA->  
<<DEBUG>> L-> 10 AS-> 0, DATA-> 356000000 
<<DEBUG>> L-> 8 AS-> 0, DATA-> 0 
<FILLER> <-- things are getting messy!
<<DEBUG>> L-> 4 AS-> 1, DATA-> 2147483647 
<<DEBUG>> L-> 10 AS-> 0, DATA->  
<<DEBUG>> L-> 2 AS-> 1, DATA-> V 
<<DEBUG>> L-> 1 AS-> 1, DATA-> 1946-10-24 
<<DEBUG>> L-> 1 AS-> 1, DATA-> 0000-00-00 
<<DEBUG>> L-> 8 AS-> 2, DATA-> A 
<<DEBUG>> L-> 8 AS-> 2, DATA-> W 
<<DEBUG>> L-> 1 AS-> 1, DATA->  
<<DEBUG>> L-> 5 AS-> 1, DATA->  
<<DEBUG>> L-> 1 AS-> 1, DATA->  
<<DEBUG>> L-> 7 AS-> 1, DATA->
```

Comment: For \@AoA, you don't need a special case to initialize the array. You can `push` onto an empty array. Your bind_column is useless, if you aren't going to *use* the variables for any particular thing.

Comment: Why don't you just put the formatting definitions from the  tblExportspecificatie table into a hash and use `print FILE sprintf` to format the output? Say you want some field to use 10 characters width, `my $width = 10; my $type = 's'; printf("%${width}${type}", 'flesk');` prints "flesk" with 5 leading spaces, where $width and $type are pulled from the definitions table.

Comment: Hey there @flesk, thanks for your comment first of all! Is there anyway you could help me out some more, i am more of a PHP guy, but the school specifically asked for PERL. I do understeand your solution, currently i am using sprintf to fix it. The function pad2str is doing that.. So the problem now is, at some part the filler shows up and the counter messes up.

Comment: @Delano: What does your pad2str sub look like? You can find the documentation for sprintf at http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html if you haven't already looked at it.

Comment: Also `if($i == 0){@AoA = ([...]);}else{push @{$AoA[$i]}, ...;}$i++;` is better written as `push @AoA, [...]`. And I don't see the reason for bind_columns and fetch in the first query when you can just use fetchrow_array and use indices from the fetched array if you must have the columns in a specific order in @AoA. I only use bind_columns if I need to retrieve a database generated value, like a sequence generated id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A significant part of your formatting code is hidden in `pad2str`. The problem seems to be how you handle 22 columns with 26 field definitions. My guess is that it is not handling the four non-existent columns at the end.

In the particular case you gave, your fields add up to a length of 254. However, you seem to be adding *both* a 2-character `$tblnr` value at the beginning *and* `'--'` at the end! So do you need 256 or 256 + 2 ('--') for record length?

Also in a given length of the large while loop, `@AoA[0][1]` is *constant*, why are you evaluating it 26`x`5 times? That's bad code in PHP or Perl.

- Fix pad2str (which you probably don't even need.)
- Decide whether you want `$tblnr` at the beginning or '--' at the end--or decide what your record length should be.
- And regard the code transformation below:

  ```
  use List::MoreUtils qw<pairwise>;

  # push behavior into statement handles... 
  {   package DBI::st;
      sub get_rows {
          my $sth = shift;
          my @results;
          $sth->execute( @_ );
          while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) { 
              push @results, \@row;
          }
          $sth->close;
          return @results;
      }
  }

  my %needs_adjustment = qw<F0101 1 F6115 1>;
  $expsel->bind_columns( \$tabelnaam, \$huidige, \$id);
  while( $expsel->fetch()) {

      $tbl   = substr( $tabelnaam, 0, 4 );
      $tblnr = substr( $tabelnaam, 2, 2 );

      my ( $first_col ) 
          = @AoA 
          = $dbh->prepare( qq/ 
            SELECT * 
              FROM tblExportspecificatie 
             WHERE tabelnaam = '$tbl' 
            ORDER BY id
          / )->get_rows
          ;

      my $adjust_first = $needs_adjustment{ $first_col->[1] };
      $first_col->[2]  = 8 if $adjust_first;
      ( $sth = $dba->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl LIMIT 5"))->execute;

      while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref ) { 
          print $fh 
                $tblnr
              , ( $adjust_first ? pad2str( 4, 0, $gemeentecode ) : '' )
              , ( pairwise { pad2str( @$a[2,3], $b ) } @AoA, @$row )
              , chr(10)
              ;
      }
      print $fh chr(10);
  }
  ```
- You *don't* want `printf`, unless you're going to supply a *format specifier*--which you do not seem to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Perl [formats](http://p3rl.org/form). They were created for that purpose specifically.